# How to run multiple REST's in a Function

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to run multiple queries in REST. But only 1st query is getting executed. Can anyone let me why so. And how can I run multiple Rest's in single function?

```
function Get_CountofCountries() {
alert('start script');
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Country')/items?$Select=Title,ID&$filter=(Country eq 'UK')",
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.d.results) {
            // TODO: handle the data
            alert('handle the data');
            var USAitemsCount = data.d.results.length;
            alert("Total Item are for USA are:" + USAitemsCount);

        }
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Country')/items?$Select=Title,ID&$filter=(Country eq 'USA')",
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.d.results) {
            // TODO: handle the data
            var UKitemsCount = data.d.results.length;
            alert("Total Item are for UK are:" + UKitemsCount);
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I didn't copy every detail from your code, but I'm sure you get the idea. Basically use $.when followed by $.then.

```
$.when(
  $.ajax(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Country')/items?$Select=Title,ID&$filter=(Country eq 'UK')"),
  $.ajax(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Country')/items?$Select=Title,ID&$filter=(Country eq 'USA')")
).then(
  (data, data2) => {
    console.log(data, data2);
  },
  err => {
    console.log(err);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use one request with an or string then use a loop to count them

```
function Get_CountofCountries() {
alert('start script');
//var ukArrayData = [];
//var usaArrayData = []
var ukCount = 0;
var usaCount = 0;
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Country')/items?$Select=Title,ID&$filter=(Country eq 'UK' or Country eq 'USA')", //Using 'or' odata query
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++){
            if (data.d.results[i].Country === 'UK'){
                //ukArrayData.push(data.d.result[i].YourField)
                ukCount =+ 1
            }else if (data.d.results[i].Country === 'USA'){
                //usaArrayData.push(data.d.result[i].YourField)
                usaCount =+ 1
            }else{
                //Country is not UK or USA
            }
        }

        alert("Total Item are for UK: " + ukCount + " Total Item are for USA:  " + usaCount);        
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

Or if you want it to be more dynamic pass in the country as a variable

```
function Get_CountofCountries(country) {
alert('start script');
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Country')/items?$Select=Title,ID&$filter=(Country eq '" + country +"')",
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.d.results) {
            // TODO: handle the data
            alert('handle the data');
            var itemsCount = data.d.results.length;
            alert("Total Item are for " + country + "are: " + itemsCount);

        }
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```